# Как вывести html тэги во vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подключил tinymce к vue.js код шаблон:

```
<editor :name="name"
        :api-key="tinymceconfig.config.apikey"
        :init="tinymceconfig.config"
        v-if="tinymceconfig"
        v-model="value"
    >
</editor>
```

код скрипта:

```
export default {
    props: {
        initialValue: {},
        name: {}
    },
    data() {
        return {
            tinymceconfig: null,
            value: this.initialValue
        }
    },

    methods: {
        loadInitialData() {
            axios.get('/tinymci/load').then((response) => {
                this.tinymceconfig = response.data.tinymceconfig;
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    },
    components: {
        'editor': Editor
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadInitialData();
    },
}
```

В шаблон, передаю данные с сервера через :props
Все работает нормально, НО как только я сохраняю что-то вроде этого
`<p><span style="color: #545b62; font-family: Roboto, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0.7px; background-color: #ffffff;">- 8 images maximum</span></p>`
При выводе [image] падает темплэйт. Как исправить эту ошибку?
Я так понимаю, что нужно экранировать, пробовал добавлять через v-html
но не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть Вашу строку в обратыне кавычки ``

Comment: Вставил, обертывание, не помогает

Comment: Эту строку Вы в `v-model` передаете?

Comment: @Дмытрык да в модели

Comment: Наверное, нужно смотреть доки модуля. Может с приходящими настройками что-то не то. Почему у Вас `initialValue` - объект, а передаете строку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С бэка нужно просто передавать данные не так {{ }}, а так - {!! !!}. поменял способ вывода переменных - заработало.